appium tests large models of voice assistants
When I used appium to automatically input to the dialog box of the voice assistant large model to open the app, the voice assistant large model blinked back, but when I manually input to open the app, the voice assistant would have a simulated click module, which could help me open the corresponding app
I checked the log break of the voice assistant, which showed that the voice assistant was forcibly disabled by the system, I asked ChatGPT, and it said that the content of the log stated that when using simulated clicks during appium automated testing, it would cause too much memory, so the system automatically disabled the voice assistant
